# Is it possible to reverse the final rounds of SHA-256

Tags: hash, sha-256, preimage-resistance

I've seen a lot of preimage and collision attacks on SHA-256 that target the first few rounds. So far, the best attacks break preimage resistance for the first 52 rounds out of 64 rounds.

However, I've never seen an attack that targets the last few rounds of SHA-256. Is it possible to launch a preimage attack on the last few rounds of SHA-256, rather than the first few rounds?

EDIT:

For example:

Scenario 1:

The attacker knows the second half of the plaintext message (32 bytes out of 64 bytes). At the 64th (final round, not including the final group operation), the hash output is X.

Can we find the output of, for example, the 55th round based on X? In other words, is it possible to execute a full preimage attack and reverse the *last* 9 rounds of SHA-256?

Scenario 2:

The attacker knows the second half of the plaintext message (32 bytes out of 64 bytes). Only 8 bytes of the hash output at the 64th round (final round, not including the final group operation) is known.

Can we find the possible outputs of, for example, the 55th round based on the partially-known output from the 64th round? In other words, is it possible to execute a partial preimage attack and reverse the *last* 9 rounds of SHA-256?

Comment: In the SHA-256 compression function, all rounds are identical except for constants, thus removing the first few or the last few is essentially immaterial. It is possible to reverse any round and any number of rounds, only the compression function as a whole is hard to invert due to the final group operation. For these reasons, I fail to make sense of the first part of the question. The second part considers fault attacks: these exploit errors purposely induced in the computation, e.g. with lasers on a Smart Card IC (in the last few rounds). It seems marginally related to the first part.

Comment: Holy crap, it needs 65 fault injections using lasers on average. What are they using, a chain gun? That's some kind of attack. Linked to a SAT solver. That's just creepy.

Comment: @fgrieu What I meant was that - for example, given a SHA-256 hash output at the final round, is it possible to find the corresponding output of the 49th round?

Comment: @Anonymous: collision attacks and second preimage attacks can chose the message and know the initial state, hence can find everything all along the hash. Thus I make sense of your comment above for first preimage attack only. Anyway, you must be ultra careful to specify what's known and not. The SHA-256 hash output is not the same thing as the output of the final round of the last compression function (unless you include the final group operation in that final round, which is unusual). Also, much depends on how much of the (padded) message is known.

Comment: @fgrieu Understood, thanks. Let's say the second half (32 bytes of 64 bytes) of the padded message is known. The hash output of the final round (not including the final group operation) is known. Is it possible to find the output of the 49th round, for example? If so, how?

Comment: If the first 32 bytes of the padded message in the last (including only) compression function are the only unknowns in the input/output of SHA-256 as a whole (as in a first-preimage attack trying to find these 32 unknown bytes), then we can find the output of the last round, and some of the output of the few butlast rounds. I do not see how we could efficiently find something as far back as the 49th round with a good degree of confidence (nor can I fully rule it out). What about cleaning the question to make it more precise, in particular stating what the attacker knows and the attack's goal?

Comment: @fgrieu That was very clear, thank you. I think I understand the concepts much better now. I've also edited the question as you suggested, to add more details.